# How to change default font and color for iTextSharp table?

Tags: c#, fonts, itext

Is there any way, how to change default table's iTextSharp font and cell's color?
I have a table, where I can change a font, but that would have to be done on every single cell - which is very unfortunate. Most probably there is a better way, but I haven't found it.

The reason I want to do this change is, that default font does not support Czech characters.

I have following code:

```
PdfPTable subTable = new PdfPTable(4);
Font bigFont = FontFactory.GetFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, 8, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.RED);
PdfPCell subCell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Bělení fáze 1",bigFont));
subCell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(196, 231, 234);
subTable.AddCell(subCell);
subTable.AddCell("Test");
```

First printed cell is going to have defined font - arial, as well as cell's color. Second cell will have all in default.

I also tried following command, but that did not help at all:

```
subTable.DefaultCell.Phrase = new Phrase() { Font = bigFont };
```

Thanks for any hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to split them into separate chunks that use different Font and add them to a phase and then add them to the PdfPTable as a cell. 
See here:
[iTextSharp - Is it possible to set a different font color for the same cell and row?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11045731/itextsharp-is-it-possible-to-set-a-different-font-color-for-the-same-cell-and)

Comment: So it means, there is no way, how to set one font as global for all texts in PDF?

Comment: Not that I am aware of or could find

Comment: OK, thanks a lot. That unfortunate, but with your link, I was able to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and came accross this old question.
While iTextSharp is deprecated and replaced by iText 7, I **had** to use the old iTextSharp.
For anyone in the same position, here is what I ended up with.

Like the original asker, I first tried to achieve it that way, which - in my opinion - would be intuitive:

```
var table = new PdfPTable(4);  // <- use wrapper class here
table.DefaultCell.Phrase = new Phrase() { Font = myDefaultFont };
```

which obviously doesn't work. But you can make it work by writing a wrapper class for PdfPTable and overriding its `AddCell(string text)` like this

```
public class MyPdfTable : PdfPTable
{
    public new void AddCell(string text)
    {
        Phrase defaultPhrase = DefaultCell.Phrase;
        Phrase phrase = defaultPhrase == null ? new Phrase(text) : new Phrase(text, defaultPhrase.Font);
        base.AddCell(phrase);

        // for some reason iTextSharp sets this to null after AddCell() is called, so we restore it
        DefaultCell.Phrase = defaultPhrase;
    }
```

One could implement this as an extension method for PdfPTable as well, but I ended up with the above solution since I was working with legacy code.
That way the only thing I had to change was the type when newing the table up and not each and every call to `AddCell()`.

Hope it helps anyone.