# How to change font to Calibri in PDF using iTextsharp for VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, itext

I am trying to change the font in a PDF file while using VB.net and itextsharp.
I think I am allmost there but I am failing at declaring  the right things.
The code I got looks ok but I get an error.

```
Dim FontColour As VariantType = New BaseColor(35, 31, 32)
Dim Calibri8 As VariantType = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 8, FontColour)
```

The errors I get are the following.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   BC30311 Value of type 'BaseColor' cannot be converted to 'VariantType'. J   C:\Users\Jeffrey\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\J\J\UniFormulieren\Offerte\OfferteUniverseel.vb  61  Active

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   BC30311 Value of type 'Font' cannot be converted to 'VariantType'.  J   C:\Users\Jeffrey\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\J\J\UniFormulieren\Offerte\OfferteUniverseel.vb  62  Active

I also tried using another method as below.

```
Dim bftimes As BaseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, False)
Dim times As New Font(bftimes, 10)
```

This way I could introduce "Times new roman" but not Calibri.
The code above would only let met add Times new roman, Courier and Helvetica.

I am using Microsoft Visual studio 2017 with VB.NET and iTextSharp.
My C# is not that great, but it helped me get this far in VB.net :)

Edit:

The first solution is something I tried using this answer from Nalan M.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29641544/9056174

Edit2:

SOLUTION

Thank you for your help ! I was so hammering on that varianttype that I was blind for another option.

Made the follow adjustments and indeed it worked like a charm!

```
    Dim FontColour As BaseColor = New BaseColor(35, 31, 32)
    Dim Calibri8 As Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 8, FontColour)
```

Thank you guys for your help. ( Still don't get why I didn't thought of it myself, using the C# to VB.net converter sometimes makes you crazy)

Comment: *"Value of type 'BaseColor' cannot be converted to 'VariantType'"* and *"Value of type 'Font' cannot be converted to 'VariantType'"* already say it all, don't they? Declare the `FontColour` variable `As BaseColor` and the `Calibri8` variable `As Font`...

Comment: As an aside: the `var` in c# is completely different from a `VariantType` in vb.

Comment: I am trying to mark your reply as the answer but I can't find out how.

Comment: It is not a reply yet, merely a comment. If that comment helped you, I'd be happy to make the comment an answer.

Comment: It helped me, you sir are my hero. Please make it an answer so I can mark it as the solution that helped me.

Comment: Ok, I generated an answer. You can mark it as accepted by clicking the tick at its upper left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error messages

> Value of type 'BaseColor' cannot be converted to 'VariantType'

and

> Value of type 'Font' cannot be converted to 'VariantType'

indicate what the issue is: The `BaseColor` and `Font` instances cannot be converted to a `VariantType`.

Thus, one has to assign them to variables of a different type. Fortunately there are natural alternatives: Let's take the known actual types `BaseColor` and `Font`!

```
Dim FontColour As BaseColor = New BaseColor(35, 31, 32)
Dim Calibri8 As Font = FontFactory.GetFont("Calibri", 8, FontColour)
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, start post updated with the solution.